# Can JNI call a method on an object during initialisation?

Tags: java, initialization, java-native-interface, final

A java class does something like the following

```
public class Foo {

    private final NativeCallbackHandler handler;

    public Foo(NativeCallbackHandler handler) {
        // I've shortened this for exposition, callSomeNativeMethod 
        // really happens in a superclass that I don't own (and is 
        // part of the lib that gives me the native part)
        callSomeNativeMethod();
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void handleNativeCallback(Object args) {
        this.handler.callback(args);
    }

    private native int callSomeNativeMethod();
}
```

You can assume that the native method does something that can lead to native code calling `handleNativeMethod`

I have 2 related questions

1. I believe the native code must call have a handle on this object and also call `GetMethodID` to get access to the method to call, is it possible for that native code to call the method **before** the object is fully initialised?
2. If it can, what are the semantics of an uninitialised final field?

if 1 is yes then I expect 2 to blow up on access it and hence I imagine we'd need to make it an `AtomicReference` in order to access it safely without blowing up.

Note I have no control over the behaviour of the native library.

Comment: Is there some reason WHY you have invoke 'callNativeMethod' before that handler field is set?

Comment: can't you just build this and run it and find out?  you seem like you're already 90% there...

Comment: because I don't own the code in the native library and this is how it can behave. The problem is that it's quite unlikely it will call this method (it's a timing issue) and I can't *make* it do this. It depends on all sorts of stuff happening in the network and when certain messages arrive and in what order which means it's v hard to deterministically recreate. Hence I need to know if I, theoretically, have a problem & if so what the problem is

Comment: Do you own Foo?  Can't you just swap the lines 'callNativeMethod()'  and 'thisHandler = headler'?

Comment: @Andrew, edited code sample to try and make it clear why I can't do that

Comment: Your biggest problem is the one that you already described.   That your 'handleNativeMethod' will be invoked before the handler is set.  Field will probably be null at that point, and the best you could do is just test for null and not invoke the empty handler field.  You could code up a test case to validate that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is possible. Native code does not enforce the `final` restriction.

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/pitfalls.html#36197:

> 10.9 Violating Access Control Rules
>
> The JNI does not enforce class, field,
>   and method access control restrictions
>   that can be expressed at the Java
>   programming language level through the
>   use of modifiers such as private and
>   final. It is possible to write native
>   code to access or modify fields of an
>   object even though doing so at the
>   Java programming language level would
>   lead to an IllegalAccessException.
>   JNI's permissiveness was a conscious
>   design decision, given that native
>   code can access and modify any memory
>   location in the heap anyway.
>
> Native code that bypasses
>   source-language-level access checks
>   may have undesirable effects on
>   program execution. For example, an
>   inconsistency may be created if a
>   native method modifies a final field
>   after a just-in-time (JIT) compiler
>   has inlined accesses to the field.
>   Similarly, native methods should not
>   modify immutable objects such as
>   fields in instances of
>   java.lang.String or java.lang.Integer.
>   Doing so may lead to breakage of
>   invariants in the Java platform
>   implementation.

This doesn't define behavior when you access an uninitialized final reference, but we can probably make a fairly good guess.

Personally, I would try to avoid the problem, either by:

- Making sure everything was initialized before the callback
- Doing nothing during the callback until a flag was set that initialization was complete.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `handleNativeCallback` from a super class constructor will lead to a `NullPointerException`, because it is invoked before the handler is set. There is no difference whether the call was made by JNI or pure Java code.

Comment: +1 Good point - and it happens whether the field is final or not. Here's a pure-Java example: http://ideone.com/0HoFk .